# Simple PHP form not working at all

Tags: php, forms

I have a very simple form with a text field and submit button,
If the correct word is inputted then it will go to another page, but if the wrong one is inputted it will stay on the page til the correct one is inputted

Heres my code:

```
<div id="pass">
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <fieldset><legend>Enter Keyword</legend>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</fieldset></form>
</div>
<?php
$text = $_POST['text'];

if ( isset( $_POST['Submit'] ) ) { 

    if ($text = One) {
        header('Location: index2.php') ;
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php') ;
    };
};
?>
```

## Update

Thought i'd update this as it got voted as "Off Topic" by a few people
Check the case of the `$_POST['Submit']` as it should've been `$_POST['submit']`

Comment: Few typos. `$text = One` should be `$text == 'One'`. And `$_POST['Submit']` should be `$_POST['submit']` (case-sensitive).

Comment: did you try `$text == "One"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if `$_POST['Submit']` is set, but in your form, `submit` has a lowercase `s`

Comment: Wow... I cant believe i missed that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($text = One) {
```

You are using an assignment statement here, you need to use a double or triple equals `==` or `===` for comparison. And `One` should be a string, it sounds like, so wrap it in quotes!

Also, I suggest calling `exit;` after your `header()` calls, otherwise your script will keep executing.